# PSInsights error Lighthouse unable to reliably load page request. Make sure testing correct URL and server is responding to requests. Status code: 410

Tags: wordpress, caching, pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I activate the plugin Seraphinite Accelerator on the website “http://tangentconsulting.ca”. After the activation, I changed the URL from our-story-2 to our-story. The Our Story page was working fine but when I checked the page speed, it gave the error “Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to all requests. (Status code: 410)”

If pagespeed insights already saved the URL of our-story on its server-side cache, how long it will take to remove or update the previous server-side cache?